# How to find input and output tensors for my tensorflow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to convert my saved tensorflow model into a .pb format. But when I see the available methods online they define an input tensor and output tensor inside the sess.run but I am not. Is there any way to find the input and output tensors? Also, why is the output tensor not getting passed in the sess.run unlike the ones that done by others? And is this prediction or classification task?
My model is shown below:

```
with tf.Session(graph=cnn_graph) as sess:
# load model
loader = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_save_path + '.meta')
loader.restore(sess, model_save_path)

# obtain tensors
x = cnn_graph.get_tensor_by_name('x:0')
y = cnn_graph.get_tensor_by_name('y:0')
keep_prob = cnn_graph.get_tensor_by_name('keep_prob:0')
logits = cnn_graph.get_tensor_by_name('logits:0')

# use model to predict from test features
# loop over test batches
for batch_index in range(test_batches.shape[0]):
    test_features_batch, test_ids_batch = read_batch(test_batches[batch_index])
    predictions = sess.run(tf.nn.softmax(logits), feed_dict={
        x: test_features_batch,
        keep_prob: 1.
    })

    for test_index in range(len(test_ids_batch)):
        # save predictions to file
        prediction_file.write(test_ids_batch[test_index] + ',' + str(predictions[test_index,1]) + 
    '\n')
        # print out predictions
        print('ID: ' + test_ids_batch[test_index] + ', Cancer probability: ' + 
      str(predictions[test_index,1]))

    prediction_file.close()
```